# Direct decompositions and quotients of abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G = \langle a \rangle_{27} \oplus \langle b \rangle_{81}$. Find a direct decomposition $G = \langle 10a + 60b \rangle \oplus ?$. Find the elementary divisors of $G/ \langle 3a + 18b \rangle$.

I'm really confused about how to actually solve questions like this. I think that for the first part, I want to find the smallest element of $\langle a \rangle_{27}$ which is not in the subgroup generated by $10a$, and similarly for $b$. However, this seems like a really tedious thing to do. Is there any other way to solve that part?

For the second part, I've only tried to find elementary divisors of quotients of free groups, not finite ones. How do I go about finding the elementary divisors here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $10$ is a unit mod $27$, it will suffice to take $\langle b\rangle$ as the second factor in a direct sum decomposition, as we can first multiply $10a+60b$ by the correct number to obtain the desired coefficient of $a$, then fix the coefficient of $b$ by adding a multiple of $b$.

Since $3a+18b=3(a+6b)$ and we have a direct sum decomposition of the form $\langle a+6b\rangle\oplus\langle b\rangle$, the quotient is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_{27}/3\mathbb{Z}_{27})\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{81}\cong \mathbb{Z}_3\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{81}$.